# Adding Amounts In consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table Employee:

Employee table has three columns as shown below:

```
ID    yearquarter   Amount
7      20171          500
7      20172          300
7      20133          100
7      20174          200
7      20181          900
7      20182          500
7      20183          100
```

Need to add the all the four quarters amounts in the year and output should have single row with 
aggregated sum like shown below.
If any year has only three quarters still need to add all three
quarters and place them in single row as output

output:

```
ID    yearquarter   Amount
7       20171       1000
7       20181       1500
```

I am trying yo use rank() function but still getting the issue:

```
 SELECT case when rank<=rank+3 then sum(amount) end as charges, max(yearquarter),id
    FROM  (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (partition by id order by yearquarter) Rank, amount,yearquarter,id 
    FROM sample where id=10004)a
    GROUP BY id
    order by id
```

Comment: why do you use `rank` here? It can be with just `group`

Answer (score 3):

Just aggregate by `id` and year:

```
select id, left(yearquarter, 4) as yyyy, sum(amount)
from sample
group by id, left(yearquarter, 4)
order by yyyy;
```

Comment: Need to add the amounts of next three rows to the current row and then place that with new amount.
Each row should be added with next three rows amount. if the table has only 2 rows left at the last 
then it should add two rows to the current row amount. ID    yearquarter   Amount
7      20171          1000
7      20172          1500
7      20133          1700
7      20174          1800
7      20181          1600

Comment: @SomasekharGhanta . . . It is very hard to follow your comment.  But this appears to answer your question.